# Fastest way to compare file content for 14 millions files

Tags: windows, azure, file, synchronization

We moved last week about 14 millions files from an on-prem file share to an Azure file share. We used AzCopy and Robocopy.

Sadly, some Robocopy tasks where killed in flight (server shutdown). As a result, some files have the same size and the same timestamp in Azure and on-prem but they are corrupted in Azure (full of zeros).

We now have to compare all files on prem and in Azure based on the content and not on the size nor the date.

What is the fastest way to compare file by there content ? Windows' fc is an option but it doesn't look fast.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy was not the culprit, AzCopy was.

I ended up by:

- Loading all the file names in a database.
- Creating a PowerShell script that calculate the hash of each file on-prem and on Azure.
- When the hashes are the same, the file is flagged as processed.
- When it's different, the file is copied again. Then the hash is verified and the file is flagged in the database.

I launched around 14 of those scripts on 4 VM, each taking care of a of subset of the database.

It tooks around a month to complete. The average file size was around 2 MB.

Hope this help.